# Expressions in Peano Arithmetic that falsify these statements?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I'm trying to find expressions ($P$ and $Q$) using Peano arithmetic that falsify these 'equivalences'.

I have some intuition about the nature of expressions using higher level theories, but not really in the Peano setting.

- $(P\implies(\exists!x)Q(x))\iff (\exists!x)(P\implies Q(x))$
- $(\exists!x)(\exists!y)P(x,y)\iff (\exists!y)(\exists!x)P(x,y)$

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first, let $P$ be any false statement, such as $1=2$.

For the second, how about $P(x,y)\ \equiv\ (x=y\lor x=y+1)$?

Comment: In the first one, if $P$ is false, than aren't both implications true? (Which would satisfy the equivalence)

Comment: Thanks for the second one, it works (as far as I can tell) and is quite instructive!

Comment: @kurtgirdle No, if $P$ is false, then the LHS is true, whereas the RHS is false (it would be true if it started with $\forall x$ or $\exists x$, but you wrote $\exists!x$)

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, I think we can try with :

> $(x > 1)$ as $P$ and $(\forall y) (x \le y)$ as $Q(x)$.

We have that $(\exists ! x) (\forall y) (x \le y)$ is *true*, so that $(x > 1) \rightarrow (\exists ! x) (\forall y) (x \le y)$ is always *true*.

But $(\exists ! x)((x > 1) \rightarrow  (\forall y) (x \le y))$ is *false*, because $(x > 1) \rightarrow  (\forall y) (x \le y)$is *true* both for $x = 0$ (because the antecedent is false and the consequent is true) and for $x = 1$ (because both the antecedent and the consequent are *false*).